# What's the structure of the clause in Italic?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> *if you look forward to the future you're going to see even more jobs in the United States today created because of if need for us to meet that growing demand we're seeing in China*

FYI, the whole sentence is

> That's what you see happening, that's why we're exporting so much to China already, and that's why our exports are growing so rapidly and that's why we're so confident that *if you look forward to the future you're going to see even more jobs in the United States today created because of if need for us to meet that growing demand we're seeing in China*.

What I cannot understand is only the finial part, showing in *Italic*.

The source: https://charlierose.com/videos/14139

around 24:00

A tip: this site has a transcript.

"United States Treasury Secretary Timothy Geithner and Vice Premier of China Wang Qishan discuss their recent meetings regarding U.S.-Chinese diplomatic relations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, it makes no sense.  The second *if* in the italicised part should be replaced with *the*:

*if you look forward to the future you're going to see even more jobs in the United States today created because of **the** need for us to meet that growing demand we're seeing in China*

But that's not the only issue.  It doesn't make sense to say that you can see something is going to happen today by looking forward to the future.  I believe the speaker just didn't think the sentence through before they said it.  The italicised part could be simplified and rewritten as:

*to meet China's growing demand, more jobs will be created in the United States*

Comment: After reading your answer, I listen (or listened?) the part again. Yes, what Secretory Geithner actually says (BTW, should I use "is saying"?) is "the need", not "if need". And we'd better simplify it as you did. However, if not, how about add "than" before "today"?

Comment: Either _says_ or _is saying_ is fine.

And you're right, adding _than_ before _today_ resolves the problem.  It still sounds strange though.  Perhaps this is better:


_if you look forward to the future you're going to see even more jobs created than today in the United States because of the need for us to meet that growing demand we're seeing in China_

Answer (score 3):

```
That's what you see happening now
That's why we're exporting so much to China already
And that's why our exports are growing so rapidly
And that's why we're so confident that if you look forward to the future
you're gonna see even more jobs in the United States today
created because of the need for us to meet that growing demand we're seeing in China
```

There's a simple ellipsis:

You're gonna see even more jobs [of the kinds that have already been created] in the United States today [as a result of that Chinese demand] created [in the future] because of the need for us to meet that growing demand.

The particular tonal emphasis placed on the word **today** in **in the United States *today*** is intended to be understood as "[of the kinds that] **exist now** in the United States" [as a result of that demand].

We can expect more of the same.